# Azure Table Storage on MacOS

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-table-storage

Since ODATA is not yet supported in ASP.Net Core, and the use of Azure Table Storage needs ODATA, does this mean that I can't use Azure Table Storage if I'm developing an ASP.Net Core application on MacOSX or Linux?

Are there any workarounds to allow my ASP.Net Core project to use Azure Table Storage?

UPDATE

I used NetStandard1.4 and it worked. I had to explicitly reference System.Linq.Queryable 4.3.0 as by default it is referencing an older version that doesn't work with NetStandard.

Comment: This: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/1.0.0-rtm-00015 tells me that OData is supported on ASP.Net Core

Comment: Thanks. I'll try using .Net Standard then.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, Asp.Net core support Azure Storage. This is [Microsoft Azure Storage SDK for .NET (8.1.1) document](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net). From the README file we know that, it supports asp.net core. Here is a snippet of the target framework that it supports:

> - Netstandard1.3: Storage Client Libraries for .NET are available to
>     support Netstandard application development including Xamarin/UWP
>     applications.
> - Netstandard1.0: Storage Client Libraries support
>     PCL through a Netstandard Façade targeting netstandard1.0.